# Symfony2 list all route with security

Tags: symfony, security, debugging, router

Using symfony2 2.7 and annotations, I define routes as follow :

```
/**
 * @Route("/my-route", name="api_my_route")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Security("has_role('SOME_ROLE')")
 */
```

I would like to list all of my routes with the associated security.

Something like `router:debug` but with the security annotations fulfilled.

Comment: What have you tried / what problems did you encounter? Haven't looked at 2.7 in specific yet, but I'd guess you could just look at the implementation of the `router:debug` command, copy relevant parts and mix some of Doctines `AnnotationReader` in?

Comment: I tried to implement a touer:debug like command but didn't manage to access the annotation.